# Hide Redirect URL in PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I have written one script in php called `login.php` using POST method to get username and parameter field and this will be redirecting to other script

```
header("Location: host_ack_api.php?username=$Userlogin&password=$Userpassword&host_name=$server&comment=$Comments");.
```

I want to hide these parameters in address bar while redirecting.
While the second script host_ack_api.php are written using GET

Comment: If you're passing by GET, you're forced to have them in the URL. You can't _hide_.

Comment: use .htaccess  to rework the URL

Comment: it is not possible with header, but you can do via form post or  file_get_contents(URL WITH PARAMETERS);

Comment: Hi Mubashar, Thank you so much. I am able to get the result in first script page using file_get_contents

Answer (score 0):

1. Option is make it by $_POST to another file or same
2. Option you can creat $_SESSION when you use your GET like you have username=$Userlogin and when you get that username make some $_SESSION variable and put data intro session and after that you can make page refresh to remove your get parameters from URL and use it from session.

PS - your method was GET not POST